# Determine if a graph exists knowing the degree of its vertices

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> **Problem**: There is a graph on ten vertices whose degrees are $9,8,8,8,6,5,4,4,2,2$

**Answer**: False.

**My attempt**: Since we know that $2 | E | = \sum _ { v \in V } d ( v )$, $$2\cdot 28 = 9+8\cdot3+6+5+4\cdot2+2\cdot2$$
Hence $| E | = 28$. Since we don't now more about the graph (it may not be a tree), how can I determine that such graph does not exist?

Comment: Is that a simple graph?

Comment: @greedoid The professor didn't precise but since we only studied simple graph this semester I assume it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose it is simple and without loops.

If that one exist then if we delete node with degree $9$ and it edges, we would get a graph:

$$7,7,7,5,4,3,3,1,1$$

now if we delete node of degree $7$ and it edges we get

$$6,6,4,3,2,2,1,0\;\;\;\;{\rm or} \;\;\;\;\geq 6,?,?,?,?,?,0,0$$

Second situation is impossible since at least one node of degree $0$ must be connected with first one with degree at least 6.

So suppose 1. situation is possible, then it is also: $$5,3,2,1,1,0$$

but this is actualy impossible (since at least one node of degree $0$ must be connected with first one with degree at least 5).

So such a graph does not exist.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is FALSE.

We proceed with the [Havel–Hakimi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm), which determines whether a degree sequence can represent a simple graph.

Applying this theorem, we note that the original degree sequence is graphical if and only if the degree sequence given by $\{7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1\}$ is graphical. We can keep on reiterating to get the following degree lists:

$$\{6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0\} \rightarrow \{5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0\} \rightarrow \{2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1\}$$

But, the last degree list is clearly not graphical: it has an edge with a negative degree! So, the answer is false.

Comment: Well, the given answer by the OP is "false" and thereby not false, :)

Comment: Are you sure you've applied the algorithm correctly (drop highest number $k$, subtract 1 from the next $k$ numbers, re-sort)? I get $\{6,6,4,3,2,2,1,0\}, \{5,3,2,1,1,0,0\}, \{2,1,0,0,0,-1\}$.